# Can I get both rewards from an Invasion?

Tags: warframe

On Warframe, there are invasions that pop up every once and a while. They give a reward (like Credits or Resources) if they are completed enough times. Some of them have 2 rewards, 1 for working for one group, and the other earned for working for the other group. Can I work for the specified amount of times for both groups and gain double the rewards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, on each mission you will have to choose a faction to support.

Changing the faction you have supported will subtract from your progress on the original faction until you are back to 0 before adding to the other faction.

So if you complete the mission 5 times for one faction and then 1 time for the other faction, you will be at 4 missions completed for the faction you first did missions for.

And since the reward is not paid out before the node is resolved (100% to one faction), you will not be able to get rewards from both sides even if you play 5 missions for one side and then 10 missions for the other side (I have tried it).

For the event they had where your total missions for a faction counted towards getting special rewards like weapons they said that you would have to have an uneven number of wins, doing 50 for each side would not get you on a winning side even though you then had complete 100 missions.

Comment: Oh damn I thought that I could do so I had 3/3 for one faction and I did quests for the other one and suddenly was on 0 and got confused + the faction I supported first got mad at me(mailed me) :'( I guess my friend was trolling me when I asked if I can do this..

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do one side for 10 missions then the other for 5 because the mission amount for the opposing faction will subtract points from the other.
so as standing Grineer vs. corpus
10 grinner missions complete/5
the 5 corpus mission like this
10/0
9/1
8/2
7/3
6/4
5/5 
And theoretically you get the reward but it still needs to be tested.